# How to call a JS function with parameter passed in NPM script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line

I am trying to run a function by calling a npm script with an additional parameter that would provide a path to a specific file. In a simplified version it looks sort of like that:

#### package.json

```
"reset_script": "node -e 'require(\"./script_reset_db\").resetDatabase($npm_config_path)'"
```

#### script_reset_db.js

```
module.exports.resetDatabase = async (path) => { console.log(path) }
```

In a node terminal I'm executing:

**npm run reset_script --path=123**

But the command results in an error:

```
at [eval]:1:44
at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:38)
at node:internal/process/execution:81:19
at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:80:60)
at node:internal/main/eval_string:27:3
```

Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [taskfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tasksfile) package it allows you to do something similar.